# SSIS How do I store dataflow data in a temporary table then attached it in an email?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssis, business-intelligence

My goal is extract data from the existed table and do some basic transformation(e.g. derived column, Merge join). After that, I want to store data into a variable. Then, I will use a Script Task to write a send email program with C#, and call the variable to load those data into my email body content. But I am confused where I can store those temporary data after few steps transformation tasks. Any help, I am appreciated for it.

1.My entire control flow

[image]

2.My data flow with few transformation tasks. I would like to know how to store data after Sort4 then I can store them into variables.

[image]

Comment: This is the poster child for why you should do stuff in queries, not in SSIS.You could really simplify this by writing one stored procedure that utilises sql mail to send your email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks ALL of your responses
I also find a solution.
I use **Recordset Destination** this data destination to help me store my temporary data. This destination can be called outside dataflow mode.
You also need to create a variable to store your data.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If this is the solution you have to accept it. even if it is your own answer

Comment: you have posted the solution (this answer) and accepted another answer (observer solution), you should accept this answer even if it is yours because it is the one that solved your issue

Answer (score 1):

**You can store this rows inside a `DataTable` or a `List` using a Script Component.**

Add a SSIS Variable of Type `Object` (ex: `User::DataList`)

In the Dataflow Task , Add a script component as a `Destination`. Mark all columns as Input. And Use the following code. (*Vb.net)*

*List version*

```
Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits UserComponent

    Public Overrides Sub PostExecute()
        MyBase.PostExecute()

        Variables.DataList = lstObject

    End Sub

    Dim lstObject As Collections.Generic.List(Of DataClass)

    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

        lstObject.Add(New DataClass With {
                    .CompanyName = Row.CompanyName,
                    .CountryName = Row.Country,
                    .EmployeeName = Row.EmployeeName,
                    .Freight = CDbl(Row.Freight)})


    End Sub


End Class

Public Class DataClass

    Public Property CompanyName As String

    Public Property CountryName As String

    Public Property EmployeeName As String

    Public Property Freight As Double?


End Class
```

*DataTable Version*

```
Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits UserComponent

    Dim dtData As New System.Data.DataTable("dtData")

    Public Overrides Sub PostExecute()
        MyBase.PostExecute()

        Variables.DataList = dtData

    End Sub


    Public Overrides Sub PreExecute()
        MyBase.PreExecute()

        dtData.Columns.Add("CompanyName")
        dtData.Columns.Add("CountryName")
        dtData.Columns.Add("EmployeeName")
        dtData.Columns.Add("Freight")

    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)


        Dim drRow As DataRow = dtData.NewRow

        drRow("CompanyName") = Row.CompanyName

        drRow("CountryName") = Row.Country

        drRow("EmployeeName") = Row.EmployeeName

        drRow("Freight") = Row.Freight

        dtData.Rows.Add(drRow)


    End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the result in a FlatFileDestination (flat file name can be configured with datetime name+datetime), and use this file as a attachment in the Send Mail Task. The attachment Path can be configured.
The sent file can also be deleted from local storage after sending email using File System Task.

[image]

You can also use third party tool (licensed) CozyRoc. It include tools like 'send Mail task plus', which support email body as html. Using script task you can create a dynamic table (html table) script which can be stored in a variable and can be displayed in the email.